# Add a jQuery id in the same line as a p.lead on pug file

Tags: javascript, jquery, pug

I am trying to edit a pug file, and I am stuck with something that shouldn't be that complex. I had a box in my page, that used to look like this:

```
.row.nested-tab
  .col-sm-12
    .card
      .card-block
        p.lead Average Score:
          #score
```

This showed the title "Average Score:", followed by the jQuery for the score at the following line. What is the right syntax to put both on the same line? Something like:

```
p.lead Average Score: #score
```

(This obviously doesn't work, I'm looking for what would :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use 'tag interpolation' for that purpose (see [this page](https://pugjs.org/language/interpolation.html#tag-interpolation) from the Pug docs).

More concretely, this boils down to replacing the last two lines of your first code snippet with this:

```
p.lead Average Score: #[#score]
```

If you want to give the `div` with ID `score` a default value (shown before any JavaScript fills fills it with the real score), give that interpolation a second value: `#[#score DefaultValue]`

Comment: Are you talking about actual rendered layout, or layout in the source markup? That is not entirely clear in your question. If you want the image to also appear on the same line as the rest, you'll need to either add CSS markup (`display: inline;` on the inner tag) or use a `span` element (`#[span#score SomeScore`), which is inline by default